# Understand a homeomorphism counterexample

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I just started learning homeomorphism and came across a counterexample showing that continuous bijection doesn't always imply homeomorphism:

> Let $X$ be a discrete space with size $\vert \mathbb{R} \vert$. Then
> there is a continuous function $X \to \mathbb{R}$ which
> has no continuous inverse.

I don't understand why $X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and why its inverse is not?

Comment: Any set is open in a discrete space. Hence, every preimage of any function is open. Thus, any function having a discrete space as its domain is continuous.

Comment: Edit your question: the $\vert \mathbb{R} \vert$ occurs 3 times - keep only the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally consider this: let $(Y,\rho)$ be any non-discrete space and $f:X\to Y$ be a bijection for some set $X$. Consider the discrete topology $\tau$ on $X$. Then $f$ is continuous but its inverse is not.

*Proof.* If $V\in\rho$ then $f^{-1}(V)\in\tau$, because $\tau$ consists of all subsets of $X$. Thus $f$ is continuous.

On the other hand, since $(Y,\rho)$ is not discrete, then there exists some subset $U\subseteq Y$ such that $U\not\in\rho$, i.e. $U$ is not open. Write down $g=f^{-1}$. Then $U=g^{-1}\big(g(U)\big)$, because $g$ is a bijection. However $g(U)$ is open (as every subset in discrete topology is). And thus $U$ is a preimage of an open subset, but it is not open. And so $g$ is not continuous. $\Box$

Answer (score 2):

Take identity map $i:X\to  X' $, where $X'$ denotes $X$ with indiscrete topology. $i$ is a bijection and is continuous.

Take open set $\{x\}\subset X$ so that $i(\{x\})=\{x\}$, which is not open in $X'$ hence $i^{-1}$ is not continuous. It follows that $i$ is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: To be precise, you need to assume that $X$ has at least two points. Otherwise $\{x\}=X$ is open. In other words for a singleton discrete and indiscrete topologies coincide.

Comment: @freakish: OP says that X has cardinality as that of $\mathbb R$.